# Windows application to view a remote web page as HTML/XML tree?

Tags: windows, html, xml, tree

I was wondering if there were a Windows application that could take a URL, download the page and displays its structure in an HTML/XML tree.

I mean this, but without having to first download the page into a local file:
[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, software recommendations are off topic here.  You can probably [edit] this question and phrase it differently to ask what you are after without asking for an application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can view the source of a page in your browser, generally using built-in developer tools. For example, in Firefox, go to `Tools`->`Web Developer`->`Inspector`. Most browsers have similar tools. You can also download extensions for this.
- You can use a bookmarklet to format the source of a page. Eg.

  - the [Snoopy](http://snoopy.allmarkedup.com/) bookmarklet. This doesn't give you a collapsible tree, though.
  - the [View Source Chart](http://viewsourcechart.com/getthebookmarklet.html) bookmarklet (tab or iframe version) will pretty print the tree in nested boxes which you can collapse/expand by clicking on them.
- If you're interested in inspecting a page's HTML, you may also be interested in other bookmarklets that let you inspect the DOM. For instance, 
  Slayer Office [DOM Inspector](http://slayeroffice.com/tools/modi/v2.0/modi_help.html) lets you mouse over elements of the page to inspect the corresponding HTML element's attributes, parents, children, etc.